# Почему не запускается rabbitmq-server?

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq

Добрый вечер. Столкнулся с проблемой: в некоторый момент брокер сообщений "завис" (перестал обновлять веб интерфейс и принимать подключения). При попытке перезагрузки командой rabbitmq-server start процесс зависает после вывода сообщения:

```
RabbitMQ 3.6.6. Copyright (C) 2007-2016 Pivotal Software, Inc.

Licensed under the MPL. See www.rabbitmq.com

Logs: /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@dbserver.log

/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@dbserver-sasl.log
Starting broker...
```

Подскажите, как пофиксить?

P.S. Команда `systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service` выдает:

```
rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-12-11 15:11:24 UTC; 15s ago
Process: 2872 ExecStop=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 2795 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=73)
Main PID: 2795 (code=exited, status=73)
Status: "Processing port mapping requests..."

Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: no other nodes on dbserver
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: * suggestion: start the node
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: current node details:
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: - node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-41@dbserver'
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: - home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver rabbitmqctl[2872]: - cookie hash: /637Yxskpg6/iDHKRZfS8g==
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 11 15:11:24 dbserver systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```